# Reset field value in case of a ValidationError

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a custom form field (subclassed from `CharField`). The underlying model has an `is_approved()` method. Now if the field is already approved (`is_approved()` returns `True`), I raise `ValidationError` and render the field as read only. The drawback here is that the HTML field has a value that I entered (and cannot save due to the `ValidationError`) and cannot even change it as the HTML field is read only.

Is there a way to change the field’s value to its original one, so my form won’t complain? Setting `self.initial` in the field’s `validate()` method didn’t help.

**Update**: after experimenting with the form class, I implemented the following `clean()` method:

```
def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
    for field_id, e in self.errors.items():
        needs_reset = False

        for error in e.as_data():
            if error.code == 'field_approved':
                needs_reset = True

        if needs_reset:
            self.cleaned_data[field_id] = self.fields[field_id].field.value

    super(BuildFillForm, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)
```

But it still doesn’t reset the field’s value.

Comment: Please provide a comment why did you downvote; without such, it’s pretty hard to improve my question.

Comment: Are you sure that `needs_reset` is set if the validation fails because of an already approved field? Will the `self.cleaned_data[field_id] = self.fields[field_id].field.value` execute?

Comment: Yes it does. But if I remove all conditionals and simply overwrite `cleaned_data`, there's still no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution by setting up `self.was_approved` in the field’s `to_python()` method:

```
def to_python(self, value):
    old_value = self.dbfield.value

    if (
            self.dbfield.is_approved() and
            old_value != value):
        self.was_approved = True

    return '' if value is None else value
```

and then using this `was_approved` property to change the return value of `bound_data()`:

```
def bound_data(self, data, initial):
    if self.was_approved:
        return initial
    else:
        return data
```

With this approach, I could even remove the `clean()` method mentioned in the question, and get exactly the same result as desired: I get a validation error, while the rendered form already has the database value displayed.